# Sql Procedure - Select data depending on state from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a search feature for a program I'm developing. The query I have at the moment checks the record state that has been selected which can be any of the below:

- Paid & Unpaid
- Paid Only
- Unpaid Only
- Deleted Records

It then does a select query which pulls all the records in which match those record states, here is the query:

```sql
    PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchSQL]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @logging_ref as varchar(50) = NULL,
    @summit_ac_no as varchar(50) = NULL,
    @contract_no as varchar(50) = NULL,
    @invoice_no as varchar(50) = NULL,
    @company as varchar(50) = NULL,
    @paycert as varchar(50) = NULL,
    @record_type as integer = NULL,
    @qs as varchar(50) = NULL,
    @records as int = NULL,
    @state as int = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    IF @state = 1 
        Begin
            SELECT TOP(@records) 
            -- Reference Columns - Used to identify a Record --
                r.r_id AS 'ref',  
                grossVal AS 'gross', 
                payCert AS 'cert', 
            -- Data Columns for Display --
                logRef as 'Logging Reference', 
                db_recTypes.recordName AS 'Record Type', 
                invNo as 'Invoice No.', 
                invDate as 'Invoice Date', 
                accNo as 'Summit Account No.',
                db_accountNo.name as 'Company Name', 
                contract as 'Contract No.', 
                taxStatus as 'Tax Status', 
                netVal as 'Net Value', 
                vat as 'V.A.T', 
                grossVal as 'Gross Value',
                paycert as 'Payment Certificate No.', 
                period as 'Period', 
                paydate as 'Anticipated Payment Date', 
                db_qs.name as 'QS record sent to', 
                sentDate as 'Date sent to QS',
                db_sentMethod.name as 'Sent Via', 
                returnedDate as 'Date Returned', 
                r.deleted as 'Removed', 
                lastModified as 'Last Modified', 
                creationDate as 'Date Created', 
                db_users.name as 'Creation User',
                p.date as 'Date Paid'
            --  Main Table to Reference --
                FROM db_records as r
            -- Proceed with SQL JOINs -- 
                JOIN db_recTypes
                ON db_recTypes.recordID = r.recType
                Join db_accountNo
                ON db_accountNo.com_id = r.accNo
                Join db_qs
                On db_qs.q_id = r.sentTo
                JOIN db_sentMethod 
                On db_sentMethod.v_id = r.sentVia
                Join db_users
                On db_users.u_id = r.u_id
                FULL OUTER JOIN db_payments as p
                ON p.r_id = r.r_id
            -- Check For the following values
                WHERE 
                    (@logging_ref IS NULL OR logRef LIKE '%' + @logging_ref + '%')
                    AND (@summit_ac_no IS NULL OR accNo LIKE '%' + @summit_ac_no + '%') 
                    AND (@contract_no IS NULL OR contract LIKE '%' + @contract_no + '%')
                    AND (@invoice_no IS NULL OR invNo LIKE '%' + @invoice_no + '%') 
                    AND (@company IS NULL OR db_accountNo.name LIKE '%' + @company + '%')
                    AND (@paycert IS NULL OR payCert LIKE '%' + @paycert + '%') 
                    AND (@record_type IS NULL OR recType = @record_type) 
                    AND (@qs IS NULL OR db_qs.name LIKE '%' + @qs + '%')
                    AND r.deleted = 0
        END
    ELSE
        Begin
            IF @state = 2
                BEGIN
                    SELECT TOP(@records) 
                    -- Reference Columns - Used to identify a Record --
                        r.r_id AS 'ref',  
                        grossVal AS 'gross', 
                        payCert AS 'cert', 
                    -- Data Columns for Display --
                        logRef as 'Logging Reference', 
                        db_recTypes.recordName AS 'Record Type', 
                        invNo as 'Invoice No.', 
                        invDate as 'Invoice Date', 
                        accNo as 'Summit Account No.',
                        db_accountNo.name as 'Company Name', 
                        contract as 'Contract No.', 
                        taxStatus as 'Tax Status', 
                        netVal as 'Net Value', 
                        vat as 'V.A.T', 
                        grossVal as 'Gross Value',
                        paycert as 'Payment Certificate No.', 
                        period as 'Period', 
                        paydate as 'Anticipated Payment Date', 
                        db_qs.name as 'QS record sent to', 
                        sentDate as 'Date sent to QS',
                        db_sentMethod.name as 'Sent Via', 
                        returnedDate as 'Date Returned', 
                        r.deleted as 'Removed', 
                        lastModified as 'Last Modified', 
                        creationDate as 'Date Created', 
                        db_users.name as 'Creation User',
                        p.date as 'Date Paid'
                    --  Main Table to Reference --
                        FROM db_records as r
                    -- Proceed with SQL JOINs -- 
                        JOIN db_recTypes
                        ON db_recTypes.recordID = r.recType
                        Join db_accountNo
                        ON db_accountNo.com_id = r.accNo
                        Join db_qs
                        On db_qs.q_id = r.sentTo
                        JOIN db_sentMethod 
                        On db_sentMethod.v_id = r.sentVia
                        Join db_users
                        On db_users.u_id = r.u_id
                        FULL OUTER JOIN db_payments as p
                        ON p.r_id = r.r_id
                    -- Check For the following values
                        WHERE 
                            (@logging_ref IS NULL OR logRef LIKE '%' + @logging_ref + '%')
                            AND (@summit_ac_no IS NULL OR accNo LIKE '%' + @summit_ac_no + '%') 
                            AND (@contract_no IS NULL OR contract LIKE '%' + @contract_no + '%')
                            AND (@invoice_no IS NULL OR invNo LIKE '%' + @invoice_no + '%') 
                            AND (@company IS NULL OR db_accountNo.name LIKE '%' + @company + '%')
                            AND (@paycert IS NULL OR payCert LIKE '%' + @paycert + '%') 
                            AND (@record_type IS NULL OR recType = @record_type) 
                            AND (@qs IS NULL OR db_qs.name LIKE '%' + @qs + '%')
                            AND p.date <> null
                END
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    IF @state = 3
                        BEGIN
                            SELECT TOP(@records) 
                            -- Reference Columns - Used to identify a Record --
                                r.r_id AS 'ref',  
                                grossVal AS 'gross', 
                                payCert AS 'cert', 
                            -- Data Columns for Display --
                                logRef as 'Logging Reference', 
                                db_recTypes.recordName AS 'Record Type', 
                                invNo as 'Invoice No.', 
                                invDate as 'Invoice Date', 
                                accNo as 'Summit Account No.',
                                db_accountNo.name as 'Company Name', 
                                contract as 'Contract No.', 
                                taxStatus as 'Tax Status', 
                                netVal as 'Net Value', 
                                vat as 'V.A.T', 
                                grossVal as 'Gross Value',
                                paycert as 'Payment Certificate No.', 
                                period as 'Period', 
                                paydate as 'Anticipated Payment Date', 
                                db_qs.name as 'QS record sent to', 
                                sentDate as 'Date sent to QS',
                                db_sentMethod.name as 'Sent Via', 
                                returnedDate as 'Date Returned', 
                                r.deleted as 'Removed', 
                                lastModified as 'Last Modified', 
                                creationDate as 'Date Created', 
                                db_users.name as 'Creation User',
                                p.date as 'Date Paid'
                            --  Main Table to Reference --
                                FROM db_records as r
                            -- Proceed with SQL JOINs -- 
                                JOIN db_recTypes
                                ON db_recTypes.recordID = r.recType
                                Join db_accountNo
                                ON db_accountNo.com_id = r.accNo
                                Join db_qs
                                On db_qs.q_id = r.sentTo
                                JOIN db_sentMethod 
                                On db_sentMethod.v_id = r.sentVia
                                Join db_users
                                On db_users.u_id = r.u_id
                                FULL OUTER JOIN db_payments as p
                                ON p.r_id = r.r_id
                            -- Check For the following values
                                WHERE 
                                    (@logging_ref IS NULL OR logRef LIKE '%' + @logging_ref + '%')
                                    AND (@summit_ac_no IS NULL OR accNo LIKE '%' + @summit_ac_no + '%') 
                                    AND (@contract_no IS NULL OR contract LIKE '%' + @contract_no + '%')
                                    AND (@invoice_no IS NULL OR invNo LIKE '%' + @invoice_no + '%') 
                                    AND (@company IS NULL OR db_accountNo.name LIKE '%' + @company + '%')
                                    AND (@paycert IS NULL OR payCert LIKE '%' + @paycert + '%') 
                                    AND (@record_type IS NULL OR recType = @record_type) 
                                    AND (@qs IS NULL OR db_qs.name LIKE '%' + @qs + '%')
                                    AND p.date = null
                        END
                    ELSE
                        Begin
                            SELECT TOP(@records) 
                            -- Reference Columns - Used to identify a Record --
                                r.r_id AS 'ref',  
                                grossVal AS 'gross', 
                                payCert AS 'cert', 
                            -- Data Columns for Display --
                                logRef as 'Logging Reference', 
                                db_recTypes.recordName AS 'Record Type', 
                                invNo as 'Invoice No.', 
                                invDate as 'Invoice Date', 
                                accNo as 'Summit Account No.',
                                db_accountNo.name as 'Company Name', 
                                contract as 'Contract No.', 
                                taxStatus as 'Tax Status', 
                                netVal as 'Net Value', 
                                vat as 'V.A.T', 
                                grossVal as 'Gross Value',
                                paycert as 'Payment Certificate No.', 
                                period as 'Period', 
                                paydate as 'Anticipated Payment Date', 
                                db_qs.name as 'QS record sent to', 
                                sentDate as 'Date sent to QS',
                                db_sentMethod.name as 'Sent Via', 
                                returnedDate as 'Date Returned', 
                                r.deleted as 'Removed', 
                                lastModified as 'Last Modified', 
                                creationDate as 'Date Created', 
                                db_users.name as 'Creation User',
                                p.date as 'Date Paid'
                            --  Main Table to Reference --
                                FROM db_records as r
                            -- Proceed with SQL JOINs -- 
                                JOIN db_recTypes
                                ON db_recTypes.recordID = r.recType
                                Join db_accountNo
                                ON db_accountNo.com_id = r.accNo
                                Join db_qs
                                On db_qs.q_id = r.sentTo
                                JOIN db_sentMethod 
                                On db_sentMethod.v_id = r.sentVia
                                Join db_users
                                On db_users.u_id = r.u_id
                                FULL OUTER JOIN db_payments as p
                                ON p.r_id = r.r_id
                            -- Check For the following values
                                WHERE 
                                    (@logging_ref IS NULL OR logRef LIKE '%' + @logging_ref + '%')
                                    AND (@summit_ac_no IS NULL OR accNo LIKE '%' + @summit_ac_no + '%') 
                                    AND (@contract_no IS NULL OR contract LIKE '%' + @contract_no + '%')
                                    AND (@invoice_no IS NULL OR invNo LIKE '%' + @invoice_no + '%') 
                                    AND (@company IS NULL OR db_accountNo.name LIKE '%' + @company + '%')
                                    AND (@paycert IS NULL OR payCert LIKE '%' + @paycert + '%') 
                                    AND (@record_type IS NULL OR recType = @record_type) 
                                    AND (@qs IS NULL OR db_qs.name LIKE '%' + @qs + '%')
                                    AND r.deleted = 1
                        END
                END
        END

END
```

The table which appears to be causing this issue is the `db_payments` as this is the table which references whether a record has been paid. e.g (If the record hasn't been paid it won't exist in here)

The `db_payments` layout is:

```
p_id  -  int  - Auto Increment
r_id  -  int  - Link to db_records
date  - date  - date paid
```

If you need the layout of the `db_records` table, I can send that.

### Altered Query

Now I'm getting the following error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 52
Incorrect syntax near 'r'.
```

Here is the Procedure:

```
USE [Sub-Con-Dev]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SearchSQL]    Script Date: 22/02/2016 09:17:28 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Marcus Gloria
-- Create date: 27/01/2016
-- Description: Gets Search Results
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchSQL]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @logging_ref as varchar(50) = NULL,
    @summit_ac_no as varchar(50) = NULL,
    @contract_no as varchar(50) = NULL,
    @invoice_no as varchar(50) = NULL,
    @company as varchar(50) = NULL,
    @paycert as varchar(50) = NULL,
    @record_type as integer = NULL,
    @qs as varchar(50) = NULL,
    @records as int = NULL,
    @state as int = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
        SELECT TOP(@records)
            r.r_id as ref,
            grossVal as gross,
            payCert as cert, 
            p.p_id as paid,
            -- Data Columns for Display --
                logRef as "Logging Reference", 
                db_recTypes.recordName AS "Record Type", 
                invNo as "Invoice No.", 
                invDate as "Invoice Date", 
                accNo as "Summit Account No.",
                db_accountNo.name as "Company Name", 
                contract as "Contract No.", 
                taxStatus as "Tax Status", 
                netVal as "Net Value", 
                vat as "V.A.T", 
                grossVal as "Gross Value",
                paycert as "Payment Certificate No.", 
                period as "Period", 
                paydate as "Anticipated Payment Date", 
                db_qs.name as "QS record sent to", 
                sentDate as "Date sent to QS",
                db_sentMethod.name as "Sent Via", 
                returnedDate as "Date Returned", 
                r.deleted as "Removed", 
                lastModified as "Last Modified", 
                creationDate as "Date Created", 
                db_users.name as "Creation User",
                p.date as "Date Paid"
            --  Main Table to Reference --
                FROM db_records as r
            -- Proceed with SQL JOINs -- 
                JOIN db_recTypes
                ON db_recTypes.recordID = r.recType
                Join db_accountNo
                ON db_accountNo.com_id = r.accNo
                Join db_qs
                On db_qs.q_id = r.sentTo
                JOIN db_sentMethod 
                On db_sentMethod.v_id = r.sentVia
                Join db_users
                On db_users.u_id = r.u_id
                FULL OUTER JOIN db_payments as p
                ON p.r_id = r.r_id
                WHERE 1 = 1 '
                 IF (@logging_ref IS NOT NULL) SET @SQL = @SQL + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'AND logRef LIKE ''%'' + @logging_ref'
                 IF (@summit_ac_no IS NOT NULL) SET @SQL = @SQL + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'AND accNo LIKE ''%'' + @summit_ac_no'
                 IF (@contract_no IS NOT NULL) SET @SQL = @SQL + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'AND contract LIKE ''%'' + @contract_no'
                 IF (@invoice_no IS NOT NULL) SET @SQL = @SQL + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'AND invNo LIKE ''%'' + @invoice_no'
                 IF (@company IS NOT NULL) SET @SQL = @SQL + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'AND db_accountNo.name LIKE ''%'' + @company'
                 IF (@paycert IS NOT NULL) SET @SQL = @SQL + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'AND payCert LIKE ''%'' + @paycert'
                 IF (@record_type IS NOT NULL) SET @SQL = @SQL + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'AND recType LIKE ''%'' + @record_type'
                 IF (@qs IS NOT NULL) SET @SQL = @SQL + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'AND db_qs.name LIKE ''%'' + @qs'

                DECLARE @lastToken NVARCHAR(100) =
                    (
                    CASE
                        WHEN @state = 1 THEN 'r.deleted = 0'
                        WHEN @state = 2 THEN 'p.date IS NOT NULL' 
                        WHEN @state = 3 THEN 'p.date IS NULL'
                        WHEN @state = 4 THEN 'r.deleted =1'
                    END
                    )
                SET  @SQL = @SQL + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + @lastToken

            EXEC sp_executesql @SQL,
                N'@logging_ref as varchar(50), @summit_ac_no as varchar(50) = NULL,
                @contract_no as varchar(50), @invoice_no as varchar(50), @company as varchar(50),
                @paycert as varchar(50), @record_type as integer, @qs as varchar(50),
                @records as int, @state as int',
                @records = @records,
                @logging_ref = @logging_ref,
                @summit_ac_no = @summit_ac_no,
                @contract_no = @contract_no,
                @invoice_no = @invoice_no,
                @company = @company,
                @paycert = @paycert,
                @record_type = @record_type,
                @qs = @qs,
                @records = @records,
                @state = @state     
        END
```

Comment: You say `The table which appears to be causing this issue ` but don't actually say what `this issue` is. What isn't working correctly?

Comment: Instead of a join, or `full outer join` in this case, try a `left join`

Comment: The way you are putting this together is a performance timebomb. As some point (and it will happen randomly) the performance is going to tank something horrible. You have two things going on here to confuse the query engine. You have a catch all query and you have multiple execution paths. The good news is this can be fixed. Gail Shaw has an awesome article on both these topics. You can merge the logic together in your procedure.http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/ and http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/09/15/multiple-execution-paths/

Answer (score 0):

Besides the suggestion to use LEFT JOIN not to miss records, I would strongly advice to simplify your procedure, by using a dynamic SQL. As it is written now, it violates the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and it is hard to read and understand.

Since your code does pretty the same thing on all branches and also used lots of filters (at least virtually), a dynamic SQL have a great chance to behave better than that plethora of `OR`s. Also, the procedure is much smaller and any change in the filters or logic can be easily achieved.

***Note***: not actually tested

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchSQL]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @logging_ref as varchar(50) = NULL,
    @summit_ac_no as varchar(50) = NULL,
    @contract_no as varchar(50) = NULL,
    @invoice_no as varchar(50) = NULL,
    @company as varchar(50) = NULL,
    @paycert as varchar(50) = NULL,
    @record_type as integer = NULL,
    @qs as varchar(50) = NULL,
    @records as int = NULL,
    @state as int = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- no need for alias quotes if they are a full word
    -- some comments omitted for brevity
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
        SELECT TOP(@records) 
            r.r_id AS ref, grossVal AS gross, payCert AS cert, 
            -- omitted for brevity
        FROM db_records as r
            JOIN db_recTypes ON db_recTypes.recordID = r.recType
            Join db_accountNo ON db_accountNo.com_id = r.accNo
            Join db_qs On db_qs.q_id = r.sentTo
            JOIN db_sentMethod On db_sentMethod.v_id = r.sentVia
            Join db_users On db_users.u_id = r.u_id
            LEFT JOIN db_payments as p ON p.r_id = r.r_id
            WHERE 1 = 1 '

        IF (@logging_ref IS NOT NULL) SET @SQL = @SQL + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'AND logRef LIKE ''%'' + @logging_ref'
        IF (@summit_ac_no IS NOT NULL) SET @SQL = @SQL + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'AND accNo LIKE ''%'' + @summit_ac_no'
        -- other filters come here
        IF (@qs IS NOT NULL) SET @SQL = @SQL + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'AND db_qs = @qs'

        DECLARE @lastToken NVARCHAR(100) = 
            (CASE WHEN @state = 1 THEN 'r.deleted = 0'
                  WHEN @state = 2 THEN 'p.date <> null'
                  WHEN @state = 3 THEN 'p.date IS NULL'         -- = NULL is not ok
                  WHEN @state = 4 THEN 'r.deleted = 1'
            END)                                                -- what happens if @state is not 1, 2, 3 or 4?

        SET @SQL = @SQL + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + @lastToken

        -- actual execution - PRINT @SQL may be used to check if the query is correct
        EXEC sp_executesql @SQL,
            N'@records INT, @logging_ref as varchar(50), @summit_ac_no as varchar(50) = NULL,
                @contract_no as varchar(50), @invoice_no as varchar(50), @company as varchar(50),
                @paycert as varchar(50), @record_type as integer, @qs as varchar(50),
                @records as int, @state as int',
            @records = @records, @logging_ref = @logging_ref, -- and so on
    END
END
```

Comment: Hi Alexei, I have created the following query but I'm getting the following error: `Msg 214, Level 16, State 3, Procedure sp_executesql, Line 3
Procedure expects parameter '@params' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.`

Comment: @MarcusITSupport - sorry, I have missed an N in EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, **N**'@records INT, @logging_ref as varchar(50), ... and TSQL does not implicit converts a `VARCHAR` to `NVARCHAR` in this case.